# Printing in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-3.5, printing-web-page, system.printing

I have an asp.net web page named "Details.aspx".
In that I have two labels named: "First Name" and "Last Name".
I have two textbox for inserting values.
I have a button named "Print"
When I click on Print button,how can i print the values entered in the textbox.

For eg:The final print should look like:-

> Your First Name Is:Mathew
>   Your Last Name Is:Thomas

Comment: I am guessing that you are getting down-voted due to lack of code depicting what you have already tried. ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is have a printer-friendly version of your page which has the content in the desired format When you click on the Print button, open that page in a new window (you can use the `window.open` JavaScript). Inside that page, call the `window.print` JavaScript function which will bring up the browser's Print dialog box.